# How to respring iDevice?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jailbreak, reboot

I am trying to make an app to respring and reboote any iDevice. My code works fine in the iOS Simulator but on my iDevice nothing happens (Yes, it is jailbroken).

Here is my code for respiring:

```
        if(system("killall SpringBoard"));

        if(system("killall -9 SpringBoard"));

        if (system([@ "reboot" UTF8String]));

        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] hasPrefix:@"2."])
            notify_post("com.apple.language.changed");

        if (system([@ "killall SpringBoard" UTF8String]));
```

and here is my code for rebooting:

```
if (system([@ "reboot" UTF8String]));
```

respring only works one time and than it stops working:(

My Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

#  Script.sh
#  Respring
#
#  Created by David on 08.11.12.
#  Copyright (c) 2012 David. All rights reserved.

app binary - root:wheel 4755

script - root:wheel 0755

C=/${0}
C=${C%/*}
declare -a flags
[[ :${DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES}: == */MobileSubstrate.dylib: ]] && flags[${flags[@]}]=--substrate
exec "${C:-.}"/Respring "${flags[@]}" -- "$@" 2>>/tmp/Respring.log
```

This is my alertView for respring and reboot with BugReport if respiring doesn't function

```
//Respring

-(IBAction)respring {

    UIAlertView *respring=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Respring"
                                                     message:@"Do you want to respring your iDevice?"
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                           otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    respring.tag = 1;       
    [respring show];
}


//AlertView   
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 1){            
        if (alertView.tag ==1) {            
            setuid(0); system("killall i5MMS_");                

            UIAlertView *respringerror=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                message:@"Respring is not possible, please send me an Bug Report."
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Send Bug Report",nil];                
                respringerror.tag = 3;                
                [respringerror show];                
        }

        if (alertView.tag ==2) {                
            if (system([@ "reboot" UTF8String]));

            UIAlertView *respringerror=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                 message:@"Rebooting is not possible, please send me an Bug Report."
                                                                delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Send Bug Report", nil];

            respringerror.tag = 4;                
            [respringerror show];            
        }                

    if (alertView.tag ==3) {            
        iDevice.text = [UIDevice currentDevice]. model;            
        ios.text = [UIDevice currentDevice]. systemVersion;            
        MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];            
        [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];            
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {                
            [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"david.goelzhaeuser@me.com", nil]];                
            [composer setSubject:@"Bug Report"];                
            [composer setMessageBody: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ \n%@ \n%@", ios.text,iDevice.text, jailbreakstatus.text]isHTML:NO];                
            [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];                
            [composer setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];                
            [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
        }

    }

    if (alertView.tag ==4) {

        iDevice.text = [UIDevice currentDevice]. model;            
        ios.text = [UIDevice currentDevice]. systemVersion;            
        MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];            
        [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];    
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {                
            [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"david.goelzhaeuser@me.com", nil]];                
            [composer setSubject:@"Bug Report"];
            [composer setMessageBody: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ \n%@ \n%@", ios.text,iDevice.text, jailbreakstatus.text]isHTML:NO];                
            [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];                
            [composer setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];                
            [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
        }


        }
    }
}


//Reboot

-(IBAction)reboot;{        
    UIAlertView *reboot=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Reboot"
                                                    message:@"Do you want to reboot your iDevice? If you have a tethered jailbreak you have to make a tethered boot after rebooting!"
                                                    delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

    reboot.tag = 2;        
    [reboot show];        
}
```

Comment: You can't do this without running the app as root, AFAIK.

Comment: please dont forget to accept answer and vote up once everything is good

Comment: can you show me more of your code because what that seems to do is once you press the second button on an alertview itll check if alertview.tag is equal to 1 (respring) or 2 (reboot)

Comment: @BbyScroopy I added my whole respring and reboot code in the AlertView

Comment: i added some code to your post use it and see if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EXAMPLE**

I will name my app Respring

In my app code I have an `RespringViewController.h` and `RespringViewController.m`

Inside of the `ResringViewController.h` I will add a button to call my respring action.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RespringViewController : UIViewController
//Creates the button
- (IBAction) respring:(id)sender;

@end
```

Now inside of `RespringViewController.m`

```
#import "RespringViewController.h"

@interface RespringViewController ()

@end

@implementation RespringViewController
//This calls the button created in RespringViewController.h
- (IBAction) respring: (id) sender {
setuid(0); system("killall SpringBoard");
}
//This makes the view for the button programmatically
UIButton *button9 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button9 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(respring:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button9.frame = CGRectMake(96.0, 262.0, 130.0, 37.0);
    button9.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = YES;
    button9.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
    button9.alpha = 1.000;
    button9.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    button9.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    button9.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
    button9.clipsToBounds = NO;
    button9.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    button9.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    button9.contentStretch = CGRectFromString(@"{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}");
    button9.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    button9.enabled = YES;
    button9.hidden = NO;
    button9.highlighted = NO;
    button9.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    button9.opaque = NO;
    button9.reversesTitleShadowWhenHighlighted = NO;
    button9.selected = NO;
    button9.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO;
    button9.tag = 0;
    button9.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15.000];
    button9.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation;
    button9.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
    button9.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [button9 setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"APPLY SETTINGS", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button9 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button9 setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.000 alpha:1.000] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button9 setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.500 alpha:1.000] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Adds the button to the view
[view addSubview:button9];
```

Now I go ahead and build it and get a file called `Respring.app`

Inside of `Respring.app` there are for example these files

> Info.plist
>
> Icon.png
>
> Respring

I have to rename `Respring` inside of `Respring.app` to `Respring_`

Now I have to upload the script below to `/path/to/Respring.app/`

```
#!/bin/bash
C=/${0}
C=${C%/*}
declare -a flags
[[ :${DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES}: == */MobileSubstrate.dylib: ]] && flags[${#flags[@]}]=--substrate
exec "${C:-.}"/Respring_ "${flags[@]}" -- "$@" 2>>/tmp/Respring.log
```

and name it `Respring`

You will now need to fake code sign the binary using the tool `ldid`

You can download it [here](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/detail?name=ldid)

From the terminal use the following command

`sudo ldid -S /path/to/Respring.app/Respring_`

Be sure to sign the binary not the script

The correct permissions have to be in place for the script to launch app as root user from terminal you can run this

`sudo chown 0:0 /path/to/Respring.app/Respring*`

`sudo chmod 0755 /path/to/Respring.app/Respring`

`sudo chmod 4755 /path/to/Respring.app/Respring_`

Everything is all set now and you can launch the app, any logs will be stored inside of `/tmp/Respring.log` of your device now and you can use the button to respring.

Comment: How to set Application as root, with a jailbreak? My iPad is already jailbroken. Must I ad an 3rd party library?

Comment: @BbyScoroopy I added the script.sh (shell script via add new file) and pasted your code (I changed myapp and myapp.log to MyAppName and MyAppName.log) but nothing happens on my iDevice when i try to respring it.

Comment: you have to rename the script `MyAppName` and your app binary `MyAppName_` does your app launch? you can also check where your log is being stored. if it says `needs to be root` or `not enough permissions` then your setup is incorrect. post your setup if your having trouble

Comment: @BbyScoroopy I added my script to the post nothing happens, the app launches but I cant respring and in the /tmp/Respring.log diractiry isn't any log

Comment: I have changed my answer and added and example

Comment: This doesen't work for me, does it matter that I have the respring comand controlled by a AlertView?

Comment: if your doing an alert view you need to make sure that the code isnt inside of the alert but in the button like so `- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        
        setuid(0); system("killall SpringBoard");
    }
}` this will work for a 1 button code change the `buttonIndex` to 1,2,3 depending on how many buttons you have so that once the button is pressed it will call on this bit of code and execute the command

Comment: I have it right implemented I think please look at the main post.